# How to get char from string by index?

Tags: python, string

Lets say I have a string that consists of x unknown chars. How could I get char nr. 13 or char nr. x-14?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

First make sure the required number is **a valid index** for the string from beginning or end , then you can simply use array subscript notation.
use `len(s)` to get string length

```
>>> s = "python"
>>> s[3]
'h'
>>> s[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>> s[0]
'p'
>>> s[-1]
'n'
>>> s[-6]
'p'
>>> s[-7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: You can pass negative integers

Comment: @AviramSegal Thanks for the correction,Yes we can, but they should also be in the limits of the string length.

Comment: after your edit its the best answer, voted up instead of down :)

Comment: This answer could be improved by using a different word with unique characters at each index.  As it stands s[3] is ambiguous as to which 'l' it is returning.

Comment: Why `s[-5]` can work, but `s[-6]` would complain an index out of range error?
So curious about the implementation in the string object in Python.

Answer (score 7):

```
In [1]: x = "anmxcjkwnekmjkldm!^%@(*)#_+@78935014712jksdfs"
In [2]: len(x)
Out[2]: 45
```

Now, For positive index ranges for x is from 0 to 44 (i.e. length - 1)

```
In [3]: x[0]
Out[3]: 'a'
In [4]: x[45]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/<ipython console> in <module>()

IndexError: string index out of range

In [5]: x[44]
Out[5]: 's'
```

For Negative index, index ranges from -1 to -45

```
In [6]: x[-1]
Out[6]: 's'
In [7]: x[-45]
Out[7]: 'a
```

For negative index, negative [length -1] i.e. the last valid value of positive index will give second list element as the list is read in reverse order,

```
In [8]: x[-44]
Out[8]: 'n'
```

Other, index's examples,

```
In [9]: x[1]
Out[9]: 'n'
In [10]: x[-9]
Out[10]: '7'
```

Comment: You should offer some verbal description of what's going on, even though the question may seem basic to you.

Comment: Updated the answer with some description, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 7):

Previous answers cover about `ASCII character` at a certain index.

It is a little bit troublesome to get a `Unicode character` at a certain index in Python 2.

E.g., with `s = '한국中国にっぽん'` which is `<type 'str'>`,

`__getitem__`, e.g., `s[i]` , does not lead you to where you desire. It will spit out semething like `�`. (Many Unicode characters are more than 1 byte but `__getitem__` in Python 2 is incremented by 1 byte.)

In this Python 2 case, you can solve the problem by decoding:

```
s = '한국中国にっぽん'
s = s.decode('utf-8')
for i in range(len(s)):
    print s[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python.org has an excellent section on strings [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). Scroll down to where it says "slice notation".

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more clear than describing it in words

```
s = 'python'
print(len(s))
6
print(s[5])
'n'
print(s[len(s) - 1])
'n'
print(s[-1])
'n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another recommended exersice for understanding lists and indexes:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for index, item in enumerate(L):
    print index + '\n' + item

0
a
1
b
2
c
```

Answer (score 0):

This should further clarify the points:

```
a = int(raw_input('Enter the index'))
str1 = 'Example'
leng = len(str1)
if (a < (len-1)) and (a > (-len)):
    print str1[a]
else:
    print('Index overflow')
```

Input 3
Output m

Input -3
Output p