# Print each 18th symbol of the string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, char

I have a string variable `L` and I need to print the 18th symbol, then the 36th, and so on in 18-character steps. They must be printed in the opposite case from the original letter (print `A` if the original letter is `a`, print `a` if `A`, etc.), along with the position of that letter in the string:

```
o   18,

o   36E

o   54 

o   72I
```

I know how to get the 18th symbol in the string, but how do I process each 18th symbol? Can I do this using `L[::18]`? And I don't really know how to transform from `a` to `A`.

Comment: It's fine that you're learning, but we'd like to see your own attempts at the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get char from string by index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848294/how-to-get-char-from-string-by-index)

Comment: The word "each" in your problem/task indicates that a loop might be useful.

Comment: any sample input!?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **[::18]** will get the characters you want.  After that, use the **isupper** and **islower** methods to find out what you have; use **upper** and **lower** methods to change.

Here's some simple test code to see how things work.  Adjust as needed.

```
test = "0123456789ABCDEFGH"*4

print "with a string", test[::18]

print "... and with a loop:"
for i in range(0,len(test), 18):
    print i, test[i]
```

Output:

```
with a string 0000
... and with a loop:
0 0
18 0
36 0
54 0
```

Comment: and what about adding the position of the letter in the string?

Comment: That's a simple linear translation; can you do the math?  Alternately, you could set up a **for** loop with the desired values and thereby have the index (position) already generated.