# Python: Moving on to the next letter on For Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, element

How can I move on to the next letter in a for loop before 1st iteration finishes?

```
s = 'mmmmbobob'
for letter in s:
    if letter is 'b':   
        s = s + 1 <<<<<<<<<RIGHT HERE<<<<<<<<<
            if letter is 'o':
                s = s + 1 <<<<<<<<<THEN HERE<<<<<<<<< 
                    if letter is "b":
                        counter_bob += 1
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    break
            else:
                continue      
print('Number of times bob occurs is: %d' % (bob_name_counter))
```

Comment: What language is this ?

Comment: It's python. But I am beginner, so it might have syntax issues.

Comment: As you're looping through a string, you can access any element by index. See [How to get char from string by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848294/how-to-get-char-from-string-by-index)

Comment: Your first mistake is not adding a language tag to the question

Comment: Your second is posting code with messed up indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're trying to add `1` to the string `s`, which will throw a `TypeError`. Even if `s` *was* an `int`, incrementing it in this fashion would not move to the next iteration of the loop in Python (or any language I know).

You can use the keyword `continue` to move to the next iteration of a loop immediately. Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

However, I don't think that is exactly what you want to do here, since it looks like you are trying to count the occurrences of the substring `'bob'` in your main string `s`.

Instead you should iterate over the indices of the characters of `s` and at each point check if the current character and next two together form the substring `'bob'`. If so increment `counter_bob`.

An example refactor of your code with this in mind:

```
s = 'mmmmbobob'
counter_bob = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:i+3] == 'bob':
        counter_bob += 1

print('Number of times bob occurs is: %d' % (counter_bob))
```

Which prints:

```
Number of times bob occurs is: 2
```